# Turn off snap to road

Tags: iphone, gps

Is it possible to turn off the snap-to-road functionality on an Iphone 5 (IOS7)?

On my commute to work I ride on a bicycle path next to a highway. The problem is that the bicycle path does not exist on Apple's maps so the IPhone moves the gps position to the closest road.

[image]
(I ride along the blue path)

This is not a single incident. It looks the same every time except if I turn off mobile data. However, turning off mobile data only work occationally. Seems like the road positions are cached.

(This happen in all GPS-apps so it is a system wide thing)

Answer (score 1):

You can ask the app developer to add an option to set CLActivityType to CLActivityTypeOtherNavigation.